# Visual Studio Code using cygwin (not working)

Tags: windows, cygwin, visual-studio-code

I've just installed VSCode (on Windows), and I'm trying run the C compiler using cygwin. I'm following this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp.

My `c_cpp_properites.json` and `launch.json` files are fine. I think it's a problem with my `tasks.json` file:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "Build test",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "test.c"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
]
}
```

I'm just trying to run a [simple Hello World program](http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html). The task runs, as the terminal says:

> Executing task: g++ -g test.c < Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

and nothing shows up at the output terminal. I can run the `a.exe` file from cmd and it works, but I rather the output be printed within VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that behavior is by design. Unless you tell it to, build task are not intended to run the program you built. For that feature, you need to turn to the debugger.

As you already have `g++` installed on Cygwin, I am assuming that `gdb` is also installed. Clicking on the debug tab on the left side of VS Code, clicking on the dropdown menu, and then selecting `Add Configuration`, then selecting `C/C++: (gdb) Launch` from the dropdown in the `launch.json` file that just opened will set you up with a blank gdb configuration.

[image: Blank gdb launcher]

Then, fill in the `"program"` and `"miDebuggerPath"` with the path to the `a.exe` file and path to the `gdb` executable respectively.

Then, the green play button in the Debug panel will be functional. When you click it, the debug session will start.

[image: Properly Configured Debug Session]

Comment: I just get a `Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.`